# How to insert an element a few elements after/before the selected element?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/e8en0htn/

Javascript

```
var addition = document.createElement('div');
    addition.innerHTML = 'TEST CONTENT HERE';
    addition.className = 'test-content';

var highlighted = document.querySelector('.highlight');

highlighted.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addition,highlighted.parentNode);
```

At the moment that code simply inserts `.test-content` just right before `.highlight`'s parent element. What I'm trying to do is inserting `.test-content` a few elements before or after `.highlight`'s parent.

The tricky part here: it can be 3 elements before/after, 5 elements before/after, etc. Because it will depend on `.highlight`'s data attribute: `data-position` should decide whether it appears before or after the element; `data-howfar` should decide how far it would appear (3 elements prior, 2 elements, etc).

I have funny ideas with `previousSibling` and `nextSibling` but apparently having too many .previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling like this isn't really convenient (especially when it the data attribute is `data-howfar="20"`... too many `.previousSibling`s).

Unfortunately I'm stuck with that solution... any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your approach on this.  What about the logic of your program makes it impossible to specify exactly where you want the element to go?

Comment: @DanFarrell it's for a forum board, so it's customizeable by user. User can choose which part of the text they want to assign the `.highlight` and where they want to show the `.test-content`.

Comment: But how do they choose where?  They're telling you "20 before what I highlighted?"  Wouldn't it be both easier and more convenient to the user if they selected the element to insert before.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying, but it sounds like the user selects some text, and a place to put like an annotation, and neither of those specifications seem like they'd be relative to anything.

Comment: This sounds like a XY-Problem to me. How about explaining what you're trying to build here, why you have to insert the node *n* nodes before/after something. Maybe there's a better and more reliable Approach to your actual problem.

Comment: @Thomas DanFarrell exactly what I said: it's for a forum board. So users can post anything they want and one of the quicktags have the option to highlight the text and give annotation before/after the highlighted text. http://i.imgur.com/ARM3in2.png They can choose where and how far it will be shown through setting the data-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be close to your needs (you can tweak it):

```js
var addition = document.createElement('div');
    addition.innerHTML = 'TEST CONTENT HERE';
    addition.className = 'test-content';
    
var highlighted = document.querySelector('.highlight');
var pos = highlighted.getAttribute('data-position');
var where = highlighted.getAttribute('data-howfar');

//highlighted.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addition,highlighted.parentNode);

var container= highlighted.parentNode.parentNode;
var child = container.children; 


for(i=0;i<child.length;i++) {
if(pos=='before') {
if(child[i]==highlighted.parentNode) {
selected=child[i-parseInt(where)];
selected.style.color='red';
container.insertBefore(addition,selected);

}
}

if(pos=='after') {
if(child[i]==highlighted.parentNode) {
selected=child[i+parseInt(where)];
//selected.style.color='red';
container.insertBefore(addition,selected);

}
}

}
```

```css
strong { font-family:sans-serif; color:#f00000; }
.test-content { background: #f00000; color:#fff; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel eu soluta adolescens, eu vel viris iudicabit definiebas, latine detracto lucilius id vis. Simul vituperata neglegentur qui ea, ex pri cibo alienum deleniti. Omnes omnesque democritum eam ea, est ut modo iriure laoreet. Possit luptatum scriptorem sed et, cu vitae audire corpora mea. Ea mea elitr tritani voluptaria, nostrud delectus ut cum. Ea per imperdiet splendide, duo ex mutat adhuc harum.
</p>
<p>
Usu suscipit necessitatibus no, sea at mazim ancillae scripserit. Nec ex facer petentium reprimique, qui ex tempor copiosae. Eum assum sensibus no. At sed vide paulo nostro, at modo postea officiis his, sale mundi aperiri at vel.
</p>
<p>
At vim civibus offendit, dolore persequeris vis ut. In eos dicant dissentiunt, cu causae epicurei est, natum veritus mnesarchum vim ex. An nam oportere adolescens. Ei diam modus iriure sed.
</p>
<p>
Cum liber dolorum fabellas id, vim dicta legimus in, natum perpetua signiferumque cum ea. In nibh viderer duo. Consul essent est ex, meis autem utinam eam ut. Quo ei errem quaestio temporibus.
</p>
<p>
Perfecto legendos pro no, vim ut imperdiet pertinacia. Te pri verear alterum, at atqui nostrud contentiones qui. Mel accumsan adolescens cu, quot singulis sea at, ex ius feugiat forensibus. Eu putent sanctus pro. No zril deserunt philosophia eum, id eum animal albucius electram, eum everti gubergren ne.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel eu soluta adolescens, eu vel viris iudicabit definiebas, latine detracto lucilius id vis. Simul vituperata neglegentur qui ea, ex pri cibo alienum deleniti. Omnes omnesque democritum eam ea, est ut modo iriure laoreet. Possit luptatum scriptorem sed et, <strong class="highlight" data-position="before" data-howfar="3">cu vitae audire corpora mea. Ea mea elitr tritani voluptaria,</strong> nostrud delectus ut cum. Ea per imperdiet splendide, duo ex mutat adhuc harum.
</p>
<p>
Usu suscipit necessitatibus no, sea at mazim ancillae scripserit. Nec ex facer petentium reprimique, qui ex tempor copiosae. Eum assum sensibus no. At sed vide paulo nostro, at modo postea officiis his, sale mundi aperiri at vel.
</p>
<p>
At vim civibus offendit, dolore persequeris vis ut. In eos dicant dissentiunt, cu causae epicurei est, natum veritus mnesarchum vim ex. An nam oportere adolescens. Ei diam modus iriure sed.
</p>
<p>
Cum liber dolorum fabellas id, vim dicta legimus in, natum perpetua signiferumque cum ea. In nibh viderer duo. Consul essent est ex, meis autem utinam eam ut. Quo ei errem quaestio temporibus.
</p>
<p>
Perfecto legendos pro no, vim ut imperdiet pertinacia. Te pri verear alterum, at atqui nostrud contentiones qui. Mel accumsan adolescens cu, quot singulis sea at, ex ius feugiat forensibus. Eu putent sanctus pro. No zril deserunt philosophia eum, id eum animal albucius electram, eum everti gubergren ne.
</p>
</div>
```

So, using of `children`, and loop through nodes... Selected child is colored red, for test purposes...

EDIT: If you want multiple elements/insertions, you could use something like this:

```
var highlighted = document.querySelectorAll('.highlight');
adds=[];
for(c=0;c<highlighted.length;c++) {
var addition = document.createElement('div');
addition.innerHTML = 'TEST CONTENT HERE';
addition.className = 'test-content';
adds.push(addition);
}
console.log(adds);
//highlighted.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addition,highlighted.parentNode);

var container = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

var child = container.children;

for (i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {

  for (j = 0; j < highlighted.length; j++) {

    pos = highlighted[j].getAttribute('data-position');
    where = highlighted[j].getAttribute('data-howfar');

    if (child[i] == highlighted[j].parentNode) {
      if (pos == 'before') {
        selected = child[i - parseInt(where)];
        selected.style.color = 'red';
        container.insertBefore(adds[j], selected);

      }
      if (pos == 'after') {
        selected = child[i + parseInt(where)];
        selected.style.color = 'red';
        container.insertBefore(adds[j], selected);

      }
    }

  }
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/e8en0htn/4/

P.S. You will (maybe) have to test/set some limits, but it shouldn't be too hard. ;)

Comment: What if there are multiple `.highlight` classes? The others seem to stop working.

Comment: @deathlock, hm... maybe one array can hold all elements with .highlight class (you will use querySelectorAll in that case, of course), and you can do nested loops or something™...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like this to get the position where the element need to be inserted.

I have tried to skip the text node in the logic but you can tweak it as per your requirement.

```
var getPosition = function(distance, direction, node)
{
 var i = 0;
 var newNode = null;
 if(direction == "prev"){
 while (i < distance)
 {
    newNode = node.previousSibling;
    node = newNode; 
    if(newNode.nodeType != 3)
    i++
 } 
 }
 else
 {
    while (i < distance)
    {
       newNode = node.nextSibling;
       node = newNode; 
       if(newNode.nodeType != 3)
       i++
    } 
 }
 return node;
}
```

```js
var addition = document.createElement('div');
    addition.innerHTML = 'TEST CONTENT HERE';
    addition.className = 'test-content';
    

var highlighted = document.querySelector('.highlight');

var distance =  document.querySelector('.highlight').getAttribute("data-howfar");
var direction =  document.querySelector('.highlight').getAttribute("data-position");


var getPosition = function(distance, direction, node)
{
 var i = 0;
 var newNode = null;
 if(direction == "prev"){
 while (i < distance)
 {
    newNode = node.previousSibling;
    if(newNode != null){
    node = newNode; 
    if(newNode.nodeType != 3)
    i++
    }
    else
    {
      i = distance
    }
 } 
 }
 else
 {
    while (i < distance)
    {
      
       newNode = node.nextSibling ;
       if(newNode != null){
       node = newNode; 
       if(newNode.nodeType != 3)
       i++
       }
       else
       {
         i = distance
       }
    } 
 }
 return node;
}
    
var node = getPosition(distance,direction,highlighted.parentNode)

node.parentNode.insertBefore(addition,node);
```

```css
strong { font-family:sans-serif; color:#f00000; }
.test-content { background: #f00000; color:#fff; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel eu soluta adolescens, eu vel viris iudicabit definiebas, latine detracto lucilius id vis. Simul vituperata neglegentur qui ea, ex pri cibo alienum deleniti. Omnes omnesque democritum eam ea, est ut modo iriure laoreet. Possit luptatum scriptorem sed et, cu vitae audire corpora mea. Ea mea elitr tritani voluptaria, nostrud delectus ut cum. Ea per imperdiet splendide, duo ex mutat adhuc harum.
</p>
<p>
Usu suscipit necessitatibus no, sea at mazim ancillae scripserit. Nec ex facer petentium reprimique, qui ex tempor copiosae. Eum assum sensibus no. At sed vide paulo nostro, at modo postea officiis his, sale mundi aperiri at vel.
</p>
<p>
At vim civibus offendit, dolore persequeris vis ut. In eos dicant dissentiunt, cu causae epicurei est, natum veritus mnesarchum vim ex. An nam oportere adolescens. Ei diam modus iriure sed.
</p>
<p>
Cum liber dolorum fabellas id, vim dicta legimus in, natum perpetua signiferumque cum ea. In nibh viderer duo. Consul essent est ex, meis autem utinam eam ut. Quo ei errem quaestio temporibus.
</p>
<p>
Perfecto legendos pro no, vim ut imperdiet pertinacia. Te pri verear alterum, at atqui nostrud contentiones qui. Mel accumsan adolescens cu, quot singulis sea at, ex ius feugiat forensibus. Eu putent sanctus pro. No zril deserunt philosophia eum, id eum animal albucius electram, eum everti gubergren ne.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel eu soluta adolescens, eu vel viris iudicabit definiebas, latine detracto lucilius id vis. Simul vituperata neglegentur qui ea, ex pri cibo alienum deleniti. Omnes omnesque democritum eam ea, est ut modo iriure laoreet. Possit luptatum scriptorem sed et, <strong class="highlight" data-position="prev" data-howfar="10">cu vitae audire corpora mea. Ea mea elitr tritani voluptaria,</strong> nostrud delectus ut cum. Ea per imperdiet splendide, duo ex mutat adhuc harum.
</p>
<p>
Usu suscipit necessitatibus no, sea at mazim ancillae scripserit. Nec ex facer petentium reprimique, qui ex tempor copiosae. Eum assum sensibus no. At sed vide paulo nostro, at modo postea officiis his, sale mundi aperiri at vel.
</p>
<p>
At vim civibus offendit, dolore persequeris vis ut. In eos dicant dissentiunt, cu causae epicurei est, natum veritus mnesarchum vim ex. An nam oportere adolescens. Ei diam modus iriure sed.
</p>
<p>
Cum liber dolorum fabellas id, vim dicta legimus in, natum perpetua signiferumque cum ea. In nibh viderer duo. Consul essent est ex, meis autem utinam eam ut. Quo ei errem quaestio temporibus.
</p>
<p>
Perfecto legendos pro no, vim ut imperdiet pertinacia. Te pri verear alterum, at atqui nostrud contentiones qui. Mel accumsan adolescens cu, quot singulis sea at, ex ius feugiat forensibus. Eu putent sanctus pro. No zril deserunt philosophia eum, id eum animal albucius electram, eum everti gubergren ne.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely. What if there are multiple `.highlight` classes?

Comment: In that case select all the elements having the highlight class and then for each perform the above solution using that particular element(this) in the loop.

Comment: @deathlock Updated the code to handle the boundary condition as well.

Comment: sorry, by multiple `.highlight` classes I mean each `.highlight`s has their own `.test-content`s...

Comment: @deathlock could you create a fiddle of this problem , i will have a look

Comment: here is the fidlle: https://jsfiddle.net/16nmoqyf/ your code seems to work nicely, only that if there are two (or more) `.highlight`s the `.test-content` only appears for the first `.highlight`. I tried to do something funny with loops but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each paragraph node will be the same this code will work. Basically I'm looping through all selected paragraph nodes checking to see which one matches the parent of the highlighted element. Then a bit of logic to check the data attributes.

If I understand your need correctly this fiddle should solve your troubles.

https://jsfiddle.net/9jjzksd3/

```
var addition = document.createElement('div');
addition.innerHTML = 'TEST CONTENT HERE';
addition.className = 'test-content';

var highlighted = document.querySelector('.highlight');
var pos = highlighted.getAttribute('data-position');
var howfar = parseInt(highlighted.getAttribute('data-howfar'));

var allNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.content > p');
var targetParent = highlighted.parentNode;

var targetParentIndex;
var insertIndex;

for(var i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++){
    if (allNodes[i] === targetParent){
        targetParentIndex = i;
    }
}

if(pos === 'prev') {
    insertIndex = targetParentIndex - howfar;
} else {
    insertIndex = targetParentIndex + howfar;
}

highlighted.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(addition, allNodes[insertIndex]);
```

If this is what you want, I'd personally abstract out that logic into it's own helper function. Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: You'll also want to put in some logic that will append your content at the beginning or end of the list if the howFar tries to set an index that does not exist.

Comment: I'm still trying to tinker with this code.. What if there are multiple `.highlight` classes? How would you make that each `.highlight` has each of their own `.test-content`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until now. How would it work with multiple .highlight classes? If you wanted the same content to be placed you could put almost all of that code in a loop, and run it once for each item.

Here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/6ej0h951/

Otherwise you could pass in the content to place to the `figureItOut` function